# Class.forname Exception

Tags: java, junit, classpath

all I'am trying to run a junit tests in this way:

I've these files:

./tested/Resta.java 
./tested/Suma.class 
./tested/Suma.java 
./tested/Resta.class 
./test/TestResta.class 
./test/TestSuma.java 
./test/TestSuma.class 
./test/TestResta.java 
./Spumevaluador.class 
./Spumevaluador.java

When I run Spumevaluador (java -cp /home/minyatur/.netbeans/7.2/modules/ext/junit-4.10.jar:. Spumevaluador) I get this error:

minyatur@orome:~/codigo$ ./ejecuta.sh 
Hola
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/TestSuma (wrong name: TestSuma)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at Spumevaluador.main(Spumevaluador.java:45)

The Spumevaluador.java code:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.junit.internal.TextListener;
import org.junit.runner.Computer;
import org.junit.runner.Request;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Spumevaluador {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("Hola");
        ArrayList clases = new ArrayList();
        clases.add("test.TestSuma");
        clases.add("test.TestResta");        
        Class<?>[] cClases = new Class<?>[clases.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < clases.size(); i++) {
            cClases[i] = Class.forName(clases.get(i).toString());
        }
        Request req = Request.classes(cClases);
        JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
        jUnitCore.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
        jUnitCore.run(req);
    }
}
```

It seems the invocation to Class.forname is not finding test.TestSuma, if I change Class.forname("TestSuma"); and include ../test in classpath it works fine.

Why? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your TestSuma class is defined in the default package instead of the test package.  Try adding:

```
package test;
```

to the top of the TestSuma.java file.

The Java classpath contains the locations where Java can find the root of the package hierarchy.  If you have a class in the test package, you need to place the directory containing a "test" subdirectory in the classpath, not the test subdirectory itself.

Answer (score 2):

Basically when you run `Class.forName("test.TestSuma")` it's trying to load a class called `TestSuma` in a package called `test`. It's looking for that in a class file called `TestSuma.class` in a directory called `test`.

It *finds* the file - but the class that it loads is *actually* called `TestSuma` in the default package... so it fails.

It's not really clear what you're *trying* to achieve, but you should keep the class files in a structure which matches the package structure, and only try to load files using their *proper* fully-qualified class name.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a stupid mistake. package test wasn't defined in TestSuma.java.

Comment: @minyatur: Look at the *source code* for `TestSuma`. It won't be declared in package `test` - but you *asked* for a class which is in package `test`. Therefore even though Java finds the file, it knows it *hasn't* found the class you're asking for. You've got to make them match up. Packages *aren't* just a matter of where classes are found.